# Issue calling REST(specifically port 443) from CRON

Tags: ssl, cron

I'm having the darndest trouble trying to perform a REST call from a cron script.

My script works fine as the root user in the terminal, but when I set it up from root CRON, I get the following error:

```
$VAR1 = 'Can\'t connect to 172.16.250.159:443 (certificate verify failed)

LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed at /opt/algosec/perl5/lib/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.
';
```

My cron looks like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/share/fireflow/local/etc/site/lib/pending_ritm_kickoff_script.pl
```

My perl script runs the following:

```
   my $client = REST::Client->new({
     hostname => ''
   });
   my $response = '';
   $client->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   my %rec_hash = (
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password,
   );
   my $json_body = encode_json(\%rec_hash);
   $client->POST("$endpoint/APP1/api/authentication/authenticate", "$json_body");
   open(my $fh, '>', '/tmp/cron_report_1.txt');
   print $fh Dumper($client->responseContent());
   close $fh;

   $response = decode_json($client->responseContent());
```

The client->responseContent is returning the ssl error.
But the script works fine from terminal! Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the first thing about perl, but you probably have something like a trusted certificate store provided by your environment, environment which wouldn't be the same when called from cron

Comment: Does the http cert verify with openssl, curl, wget or other program?

Answer (score 1):

The solution ended up being to add an Environment variable to the Perl Script, ignoring the SSL validation:

$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME}=0;